# RabbitMQ max-hops where to declare this?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am trying to figure out how to set the **max-hops** against a federated policy that I want to make, but the documentation doesn't say where to put this within the command.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/federated-exchanges.html

Is it just like this, note I have put max-hops at the end:

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-fed "^MyExchange" '{"federation-upstream-set":"all", "ha-sync-mode":"automatic"' --priority 10 --apply-to exchanges --max-hops 1
```

or does the max-hops go inside the JSON block?

The documentation doesn't help by saying max-hops=1 which is neither a JSON colon declaration or a command line one with the space?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer I was getting confused that it should be in the above command but imagine it belongs in this command around declaring a federated upstream.

[image]

Not entirely sure where to specify it in the command, but I did find that the default value is 1 which is just what I wanted anyway.

```
rabbitmqctl set_parameter federation-upstream upstream-from-cluster2 '{"uri":"amqp://name:password@myipaddress:5674"}'
```